# Condicional en python con bytes b' '

Tags: python

Mi código recibe un byte por el puerto serie del tipo b'\x0X'

El byte recibido puede tener un rango 0x00 hasta 0xFF

Necesito filtrar el valor del byte recibido para redirigir el flujo

Lo que he hecho es una función que recibe el byte como parámetro.
Con sentencias  if /elif creo los condicionales, (==, < >, is, not , etc. ) pero no entra en el IF
solo entra si establezco == b'\x0F' cuando mi pretensión es comparar con 0x0F, 0x01F, 0x2A, etc.
porque es lo que se refleja en las especificaciones del sistema que estoy monitorizando

He mirado y remirado por este y otros foros y aunque tengo una solución (b'\x0F') no me quiero dar por vencido

Os paso el extracto de código :

Recepción por puerto serie:

```
    pollRx = conexion.read()

    if pollRx != b'\x00': 

        f_switch(pollRx)
```

Función para filtrar el byte recibido

```
    def f_switch(excepcion):

      if excepcion is 0x1F:
         exc_Log = excepcion + " --- Puerta  abierta"


      elif excepcion is 0x4A: 
         exc_Log = excepcion + " --- Puerta  cerrada"
```

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Es natural imaginar un byte en función de la tabla Ascii y asumir que `b'\x03'` es mayor `b'\x02'`, pero conceptualmente un byte puede ser cualquier cosa, entonces ¿Cómo saber que un byte es mayor o menor a otro?. Lo que si puedes es evaluar los bytes como enteros y entonces sí hacer las comparaciones pertinentes:

```
pollRx = b'\x03'

if int.from_bytes(pollRx, "big") >=  int.from_bytes(b'\x03', "big"):
  print("Es mayor o igual")
else:
  print("Es menor")
```

[`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) requiere el **byteorder** que establece dónde están los bytes más significativos (al comienzo o al final) esto es algo que depende del hardware, sin embargo no tiene importancia en tu caso por que solo estás comparando de a un byte.